# Continuity Proving

Tags: functions, continuity

I have the functional relationship:
$$[f(x)]^3+f(x)=2x,\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$$
I have already proved that the function $f$ is continuous at $x_0=0$, but now I want to prove that is continuous at $\mathbb{R}$. Any ideas?

Comment: what is denoted by $$f^3(x)$$?

Comment: @Fred How do you know that? It might just as well be $f(f(f(x)))$.

Comment: $f^3(x)=[f(x)]^3$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\lim_{h\to 0} \, \left(f^3(c+h)+f(c+h)\right)=\lim_{h\to 0}\, 2(c+h)=2c=f^3(c)+f(c)$$
for any $c\in\mathbb{R}$ therefore $f(x)$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Raffaele. Please elaborate. You have:  lim parenthesis = lim 2x, ok. Right hand side, continuous, limit is 2c, where do you go from here, can you infer that each indiv.  limit, left hand side exists, f^3(c) ,f(c)? And f is cont. Thanks, Peter